# drawing a circle pgf complaining that no shape A,F is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I'm trying to circumscribe a triangle with a circle.  I'm using `tkz-euclide` and referring to a few past posts to this forum, am using the macro `\tkzDefCircle` with the same points as those used for the equilateral triangle (since those points lay on the circumference of the circle).  Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.5]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0);
\tkzDefEquilateral(B,A)\tkzGetPoint{F};
\tkzDrawPolygon(B,A,F);
\tkzDefCircle(B,A,F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The compilation error I'm getting is, "Package pgf Error: No shape named A,F is known."  I'm not understanding why.  Doesn't the `\tkzGetPoint{F}` macro define a new coordinate by that name?  After all, that point seemed to exist to pgf's liking for the triangle.  Why is now invalid for the circle?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\tkzDefCircle` macro can either produce a circle with a centre and point on circumference or a circle through three points.  The default is the former, to specify the second, you need to pass the key `circum`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
% \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341955/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.5]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0);
\tkzDefEquilateral(B,A)\tkzGetPoint{F};
\tkzDrawPolygon(B,A,F);
\tkzDefCircle[circum](B,A,F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my best Dr. Who voice, "Fantastic!"  That's some nice wizardry in whoever produced this Euclide adaptation for tikz.  I do wish the manual weren't in French.